# dynamic dropdown selection in jqquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a field as :

```
 <span>Color Set By</span> 
 <select class="full select" id="mapcolor">
    <option value =1 selected >Difference in Final Price</option>
    <option value =2 >Difference in Regular Price</option>
    <option value =3 >Difference in Final Price/Shipping</option>
 </select>
```

but when option value passed by another function is, say, 2 i need to change to change the selection. as well as deselect the previous. its and dropdown. is my code correct for this:

```
var mapid=getPresetFilters(mapcolor);
if(mapid!==$('select#mapcolor').val()) {
    $("#mapcolor option[value=mapid]").attr("selected", "selected");
}
```

Comment: Did you try to set value for select by .val(mapid) ?

Comment: Just do `$('#mapcolor').val(mapid)`...no need for `if` or setting selected on option

Comment: @StupidDev is wiriting this options in html and then trying to get selected values in js for the first time with $('select#mapcolor').val() will give me "1". just asking.

Comment: $('select#mapcolor').val() <= get value but $('select#mapcolor').val(sth) <= set

Answer (score 0):

You can use [.val()](http://api.jquery.com/val/) to set the selected value of a select element

```
$('#mapcolor').val(mapid);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/3cstZ/)

In your case the `mapid` is a variable holding the desired value of the select element, you your code should have been

```
$('#mapcolor option[value="' + mapid + '"]').prop("selected", true);
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/833VG/)

Comment: is wiriting this options in html and then trying to get selected values in js for the first time with $('select#mapcolor').val() will give me "1". just asking.